# Permutations and combinations for team problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

[image]

I am having hard time answering these questions. For 1st one I have answered $ 11×3^{10} $, because 11 people to choose from the goalkeeper and each other player has three options. Can someone please check if this is correct? It seems to me that first and third questions are asking the same, is it right?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I agree with the answer of $11\cdot 3^{10}$ for the *third* problem.  Given that the third problem is asked in addition to the first problem, it is highly probable that the nuance and meaning of the problems is intended to be different.  For that reason, I expect that in the first problem the players are all considered identical and the only distinguishing factors between arrangements are *how many* (*but not who*) play each position.

Comment: For part (a) then, it becomes a question on stars-and-bars.  Letting $d,m,s$ refer to the number of players playing defender, midfielder, and striker respectively, I interpret the question to be asking for the number of non-negative integer solutions to the system $\begin{cases}d+m+s=10\\d\geq 0\\m\geq 0\\s\geq 0\end{cases}$, and for the second problem asking for the number of integer solutions to $\begin{cases}d+m+s=10\\d\geq 2\\m\geq 2\\s\geq 2\end{cases}$, still ignoring who is who.

Comment: I think in (a) and (b), the word configuration implies just the numbers at each position. So this becomes a stars and bars problem. (a) $\binom{12}{3}$; (b) $\binom{6}{3}$; (c) $11*3^{10}$

Comment: Thank you all so much for clarifying!